# Combining class selector with attribute selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="somelink.htm" class="button columns large-6">wide button</a>
<a href="somelink.htm" class="button columns large-3">narrow button</a>
```

I've tried using an attribute selector and combining it with the `button` class but it doesn't work as expected.

```
.button.[class*="large-"] {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Am I using this correctly and if not, how?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need the second period, unlike JavaScript the `[class*="large-"]` isn't compiled to return the found-string, it's simply evaluated as-is:

```
.button[class*="large-"] {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mudHv/).

Answer (score 5):

You are using ***[attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)*** using `[class*="large-"]` and so you don't need to use `period(.)` ie *class selector* here. Just simply write this

```
.button[class*="large-"] {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color:red;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rY2eh/)

Answer (score 2):

```
.button[class*="large-"] {
   font-size: 0.9em;
}

<a href="somelink.htm" class="button columns large-6">wide button</a>
<a href="somelink.htm" class="button columns large-3">narrow button</a>
<a href="somelink.htm" class="button columns large">narrow button</a>
<a href="somelink.htm" class="large-2">narrow button</a>
```

this seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.button[class*=large] {
 font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Comment: It should be known that not using quotes inside attribute selectors is now considered invalid. https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors